# Paypal recurring payment response verification and match with paypal return page variable

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on a website to sell some advertisement concept online, where user can get the access of more options after opting a monthly subscription paying through  recurring Paypal.
I have already implemented the recurring paypal functionality successfully except one thing. Like One can subscribe for the plan and monthly payments are deducted from the concerned account.
But I have no idea how to update my database after the first payment from the recurring paypal.
eg, a customer comes to the site, choose his options, went to paypal recurring part and made the transaction. Now I have one page , where the paypal returns the control, which is given on the return url. Now the problem is, in this page when I am updating the database, the paymanet status is pending. 
Then after a while when the IPN response comes to the application, I wont able to update the earlier entry in my database, as I am not sure how to match these two entries, I mean upon which field the update query should be coded.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in updating the database at all until you get the money. When you get the money, the transaction contains everything you need to create or update the subscription.